# Seleccionar posiciones de un vector. Python

Tags: python

Estoy traduciendo de R studio a Python y me ha surgido una duda, en R estoy usando `which` que lo que hace es dar los índices `TRUE` de un objeto lógico, permitiendo los índices del array. Por ejemplo, si tengo un vector `v=(0,5,6,7,81,4,8,2,4,1,3)`
y pongo `which(v>=6)` y devuelve este resultado `3 4 5 7` devuelve las posiciones mayores a 6,

¿Cómo se haría esto en Python?

Comment: Hola, para los que no sabemos nada de R, ¿de qué posiciones estamos hablando?, ¿posiciones del vector?

Comment: Si, posiciones del vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo simple de como podrias recuperar estos valores

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [x>3 for x in a] #[False,False,False,True,True]
c = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x<=3] #Recuperas los indices que cumplen la condicion
```

En si me parece que c seria lo que te serviria, esto con implementacion de codigo estandar, pero librerias como numpy podrian facilitarte esta y otras tareas

Con numpy la recuperacion de los indices podría hacerse asi:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
c = np.where(a>3) #Devuelve un arreglo de numpy con los indices que cumplen la condicion
#Puedes acceder a los datos asi:
c[0][0]#[fila][columna]
```

Para este ejemplo tal vez parezca mas rebuscado, pero al trabajar con mas datos numpy es mas eficaz y cuenta con sintaxis mas limpia.

Comment: ¿Y como sería con una libreria de Numpy? Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Ya he editado mi respuesta para que puedas ver como seria en numpy, tal vez se te haga una sintaxis mas familiar a R

Comment: y si por ejemplo querria que el python contase la longitud, es que estoy intentando poner  len(np.where(a>3)) y no me deja.

Answer (score 3):

La traducción más aproximada es la siguiente:

```
lista = [0,5,6,7,81,4,8,2,4,1,3]
print([i for i, e in enumerate(lista,1)  if e >= 6])
[3, 4, 5, 7]
```

es decir, generamos una nueva lista recorriendo la original enumerando cada elemento desde 1 (En R los vectores comienzan con el índice 1, en Python con 0) y nos quedamos con el índice sol si el valor `e`es >= 6.

Comment: Ah, ya veo. Las posiciones en R empiezan desde 1. Ahora tiene sentido.

Answer (score 2):

Aquí tienes algunas opciones mas:

```
# Datos
v=(0,5,6,7,81,4,8,2,4,1,3)

# Numpy, forma breve.
np.array(np.array(v)>5).nonzero()
Out[1]: (array([2, 3, 4, 6], dtype=int64),)

# Compresion de listas
[idx for idx in range(len(v)) if v[idx] > 5]
Out[2]: [2, 3, 4, 6]

# map y filtrado
list(map(v.index, filter(lambda x : x>5, v)))
Out[3]: [2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Si piensas usarlo más veces una función bastante útil:

```
def indices(list, filtr=lambda x: bool(x)):
    return [i for i,x in enumerate(list) if filtr(x)]

print(indices(v, lambda x: x>5))
Out[4]:[2, 3, 4, 6]
```